# Decrease the size of shadows when doing a screen capture in OS X Lion?

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, osx-lion, gui, screen-capture

When taking a screenshot in Mac OS X Lion, I've noticed the shadows appear to be a lot larger than in Snow Leopard. Perhaps they just fade more gradually and this takes up more space. Whatever the case it is a bit annoying.

I've found a bit of code (below) that allows one to disable shadows from being captured in OS X Lion's screenshots by default:

```
defaults write com.apple.screencapture disable-shadow -bool true

killall SystemUIServer
```

But I sort of like the shadows, just not "that much" of them. Is there a way to decrease the shadows without turning them off completely?

Example of the calculator window with huge shadows in Lion (red is edge of screenshot):

[image]

Compare to Snow Leopard:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the screenshots while the window is not the focused window. Calculator on OS X Lion:

[image]

If you don't like the look, you can always take two screenshots:

- one screenshot with unfocused window and shadow
- one screenshot focused without shadow

Then merge them. It takes a basic image editor with layers and is really easy to do, you just need to move the shadowless layer a bit below center, since the bottom shadow is bigger than the top shadow. Here's the shadowless image I used:

[image]

Here's the final result after less than a minute in Pixelmator:

[image]

Comment: Not exactly the way I thought this would be accomplished, but not a bad trick - very creative. BTW - Do you have both PS and Pixelmator or is the second one a replacement? I've looked at it a few times but have not yet tried / bought.

Comment: @cwd I know little about Photoshop. Pixelmator suffices for my needs.